# Can't send a new register to my database mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem, when i try insert a new register in my datebase, where the input is {"url": "example.com"}, i'm using express framework, mongodb datebase and library mongoose(i already got create a new id, get a url with id, delete a id..., just this i cant)

here i acess my database and try to change it

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Chaordic = mongoose.model('Chaordic');

// Add a new URL 
exports.addUrl = (req,res,next) => {

var chaordic = new Chaordic();
chaordic.id = req.params.id;
chaordic.url = req.body.url;
chaordic.hits = 0;
chaordic.shortUrl = shortenUrl(chaordic.url)
chaordic.save().then(x =>{
    res.status(201).send({
        id: chaordic.id
    });
}).catch(e =>{
    res.status(204).send(e);
})
}
```

here i send a request for server

```
const express = require('express');
const router  = express.Router();
const controller = require('../controllers/controller');

router.post('/users/:id/urls', controller.addUrl);

module.exports = router;
```

and here is my model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const schema = new Schema({
id: {
    type:String,
    unique: true

},
url: {
    type: String
},
hits: {
    type: Number
},
shortUrl: {
    type: String
}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Chaordic', schema);
```

When i send a request for server, server return's error 204 (because i put it with error msg) Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new document with:

```
var chaordic = new Chaordic();
```

Mongoose generates an _id property that contains a BSON ObjectId.

By default, every schema has a getter function attached to a [virtual](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals) property named `id`. This getter function, returns a string representation of the BSON ObjectId stored in _id.

The schema does not have a setter assigned to the [virtual](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals) named `id`, so when you try to assign a value like:

```
chaordic.id = req.params.id;
```

*It isn't going to work.*

**Consider this example:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const schema = new Schema({});

const Test = mongoose.model('test', schema);

const test = new Test({});

test.id = 'this is not going to work.';

console.log(test.id);
```

**outputs:**

```
5ad37f0fb000cf81a881600f
```

#### The Bottom Line

You have 2 choices:

1. Set the schema option id: false to disable the default getter

   ```
   schema.set('id', false)
   ```
2. Change the name of your id path to something else.

   ```
   const schema = new Schema({
   myID: {
     type:String,
     unique: true

   },
   url: {
     type: String
   },
   hits: {
     type: Number
   },
   shortUrl: {
     type: String
   }
   });
   ```

The second choice is the one I would recommend, it's nice to be able to get the string version of the BSON ObjectId without having to convert it with String yourself.